# problemas validando con keyup, javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

```js
$(function(){
 $('input').keyup(validationUser);
})
function validationUser(){
 $('.alerta').remove();

 let userName = $('#userName').val(),
  userEmail = $('#userEmail').val()

 if (userName == "") {
  $('#userName').parent().after('<div class="alerta">Please enter name.</div>')
  return false;
 }
 if (userEmail == "") {
  $('#userEmail').parent().after('<div class="alerta">Please enter Email.</div>')
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
 <form onsubmit="return validationUser()">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>User</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit form</button>
</form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El problema que tengo es cuando escribo en el campo "userName", automaticamente aparece el mensaje de error del siguiente campo "emailUser".Cuando todavia no le di click en el submit. Ademas, estoy intentando validar en tiempo real con keyup o tal vez me recomiendan otro metodo para validar en tiempo real.

Comment: mira tu código, en el evento keyup estas llamando la función validationUser, en la lógica de esta estas ejecutando ambas validaciones.

Comment: he intentando varias cosas, incluso he creado 2 funciones para ejecutar cada tarea por separado, peor igual no funciona.

Comment: creo que la validacion deberias hacerla en on submit del formulario mas que en el evento  keyup

Comment: alguna otra opcion ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 
 let errorUserName = false,
   errorUserEmail = false,
  errorUserPassword = false;

 $('#nameRegister').keyup(function(){
  validationUserName();
 });
 $('#emailRegister').keyup(function(){
  validationUserEmail();
 });
 $('#passwordRegister').keyup(function(){
  validationUserPassword();
 });

 function validationUserName(){
  let regExpName = /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/,
   userName = $('#nameRegister').val()
  if (userName == "") {
   $('#errorUserName').show().css('color','red').html('Enter name please..');
   $('#nameRegister').css('border','2px solid red');
   $('#labelUserName').css('color','red');
   $('.errorIconName').show();
   $('.okIconName').hide();
   errorUserName = true;
  }else if (!regExpName.test(userName)) {
   $('#errorUserName').show().css('color','red').html('Special characters or numbers are not allowed');
   $('#nameRegister').css('border','2px solid red');
   $('#labelUserName').css('color','red');
   $('.errorIconName').show();
   $('.okIconName').hide();
   errorUserName = true;
  }else {
   $('#errorUserName').hide();
   $('.errorIconName').hide();
   $('.okIconName').show();
   $('#labelUserName').css('color','green');
   $('#nameRegister').css('border','2px solid green');
  }
 }
 function validationUserEmail(){
  let regExpEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/,
   userEmail = $('#emailRegister').val()
  if (userEmail == "") {
   $('#errorUserEmail').show().css('color','red').html('Enter email please..')
   $('#labelUserEmail').css('color','red');
   $('#emailRegister').css('border','2px solid red');
   $('.okIconEmail').hide();
   $('.errorIconEmail').show();
   errorUserEmail = true;
  }else if (!regExpEmail.test(userEmail)) {
   $('#errorUserEmail').show().css('color','red').html('Incorrect email : example@hotmail.com');
   $('#labelUserEmail').css('color','red');
   $('#emailRegister').css('border','2px solid red');
   $('.errorIconEmail').show();
   $('.okIconEmail').hide();
   errorUserEmail = true;
  }else {
   $('#errorUserEmail').hide();
   $('.errorIconEmail').hide();
   $('.okIconEmail').show();
   $('#labelUserEmail').css('color','green');
   $('#emailRegister').css('border','2px solid green');
  }
 }
 function validationUserPassword(){
  let regExpPassword = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-záéíóúüñ]).*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]/,
   userPassword = $('#passwordRegister').val()
  if (userPassword == "") {
   $('#errorUserPassword').show().css('color','red').html('Enter password please..')
   $('#labelUserPassword').css('color','red');
   $('#passwordRegister').css('border','2px solid red');
   $('.errorIconPassword').show();
   $('.okIconPassword').hide();
   errorUserPassword = true;
  }else if (!regExpPassword.test(userPassword)) {
   $('#errorUserPassword').show().css('color','red').html('Enter lowercase, uppercase and number')
   $('#labelUserPassword').css('color','red');
   $('#passwordRegister').css('border','2px solid red');
   $('.errorIconPassword').show();
   $('.okIconPassword').hide();
   errorUserPassword = true;
  }else {
   $('#errorUserPassword').hide();
   $('.errorIconPassword').hide();
   $('.okIconPassword').show();
   $('#labelUserPassword').css('color','green');
   $('#passwordRegister').css('border','2px solid green');
  }
 }

 $('#formRegisterUser').submit(function(){
  errorUserName = false;
  errorUserEmail = false;
  errorUserPassword = false;

  validationUserName();
  validationUserEmail();
  validationUserPassword();

  if (errorUserName == false && errorUserEmail == false && errorUserPassword == false) {
      alert('Thank you for registering');
   return true;
  }else {
   return false;
  }
 })
})
```

```css
.form-group {
 position: relative;
}
.fa {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 padding: 11px;
}
.fa-check {
 color: green;
}
.fa-times {
 color: red;
}
.errorIconName, .okIconName, .errorIconEmail, .okIconEmail, .errorIconPassword, .okIconPassword {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method="post" id="formRegisterUser" autocomplete="off">
         <h1 class="modalTitulo">Registrarse</h1>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label id="labelUserName">User Name</label>
        <div class="errorIconName">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="okIconName">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameRegister">
        <span id="errorUserName"></span>  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label id="labelUserEmail">Email</label>
          <div class="errorIconEmail">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
          </div>
        <div class="okIconEmail">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailRegister">
        <span id="errorUserEmail"></span> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label id="labelUserPassword">Password</label>
          <div class="errorIconPassword">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
          </div>
        <div class="okIconPassword">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordRegister">
        <span id="errorUserPassword"></span>
      </div> 
      </div>
   <div class="cajaOlvidoContrasena">
    <span class="olvidoContrasena">Ya Tiene Una Cuenta ?<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal"><strong> Click Aqui</strong></a></span>
   </div>
   <div class="cajaBotonRegistrarse">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary botonRegistrarse">CREAR CUENTA</button>
   </div>
        </form>
```

Bueno, a las finales he hecho un codigo muy larg, pero ya funciona. El pequeño problema que ahora tengo seria con el "tab", pero intentare ver si puedo solucionarlo, pero ya esta validado.
Si alguien tiene una manera mas sencilla de poder validar, por favor diganme.